# Returning variable size byte array and free the memory

Tags: objective-c, c, openssl, pass-by-reference

I am writing a proxy .c file for using `OpenSSL` library for RSA encryption. Usable for iPhone. Since encrypted data sized is not known to the calling class in Objective C, the container is not initialized and I want to keep it dynamic. The char array and the received size is called by reference. Its memory is dynamically allocated in `ssl_encrypt_public_rsa` and the caller has to free it. I don't like the idea to give the responsibility to the caller.

Is there any other robust method that you can suggest?

`openssl` implementation in .c (later compiled to static lib .a file)

```
// calling function must free cipherText memory
void ssl_encrypt_public_rsa(RSA *rsaKey, int plainLength, unsigned char *plainText,
                              int *cipherLength, unsigned char **cipherText)
{
    int enc_len = RSA_size(rsaKey);
    unsigned char *enc_bytes = malloc(enc_len * sizeof(char));
    int encSize = RSA_public_encrypt(plainLength, plainText, enc_bytes, rsaKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    *cipherText = enc_bytes;
    *cipherLength = encSize;
}

void ssl_encrypt_mips(int plainLength, unsigned char *plainText,
                        int *cipherLength, unsigned char **cipherText)
{
// rsaKeyMips is defined and initialized earlier
    ssl_encrypt_public_rsa(rsaKeyMips, plainLength, plainText, cipherLength, cipherText);
}
```

**Calling function Objective C .m file**

```
-(NSData *) encryptMips:(NSData *)inData
{
    int encSize = 0;
    unsigned char *cipherBytes;
    ssl_encrypt_mips((int)inData.length, (unsigned char *)inData.bytes, &encSize, &cipherBytes);
    if (encSize == -1 ) return nil;
    NSData * d = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBytes length:encSize];
    free(cipherBytes);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. Using `NSData` object to return bytes from your code already lets your callers rely on ARC to free the data once it is no longer needed. Callers of `encryptMips` don't need to free anything, right?

Comment: cipherBytes is allocated using malloc. Should not it be freed?

Comment: But you already call `free(cipherBytes);` before returning `d`, right?

Comment: Yes, my question is, is there any other robust way to do it without giving the caller responsibility to free cipherBytes.

Comment: Not in "plain" C, only in Objective-C. Do you expect the users of your code interact with `ssl_encrypt_public_rsa` directly? If so, wrap it in Objective-C code the way you did `encryptMips`, and return `NSData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are asking, as you've already wrapped the C call in a wrapper which takes care of the `free()`. If you wish to remove the `free()` from your wrapper, and serendipitously avoid a copy, you can change your:

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBytes length:encSize];
free(cipherBytes);
```

to:

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:cipherBytes length:encSize free:YES];
```

which hands ownership of the `malloc()` block to the `NSData` instance, which will `free()` it later when no longer needed.

HTH